# Using the AutoCompleteExtender with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit, webmethod

How is everyone today?

**The Problem**

Basically, I'm delving into the world of the AjaxControlToolkit today, with the main aim of fulfilling my AutoComplete requirements. I've set everything up as tutorialised and am a little confused as to why things aren't working (well I have an inkling as to what may be holding me back).

I've added the AjaxControlToolkit dll to my project and in my Markup I have the following :

at the top

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxControlToolkit" %>
```

then within my content

```
<ajaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxControlToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" CssClass="search"></asp:TextBox>

<ajaxControlToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="autoCompleteSearchExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtSearch" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"></ajaxControlToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Then in the code behind, I have my nice little function (which the breakpoint within is never reached)

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()> _
    Public Function GetCompletionList(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer, ByVal contextKey As String) As String()
        ' Get current list
        Dim myList As List(Of MyClass) = GetSearchResultList()

        Return (From s In myList Select s.Name).ToArray()
    End Function
```

The function is never being called, for a reason I am unsure of.

**Potential Issues**
There are a couple of potential issues where things may be going wrong:

- I've tried adding the AjaxControlToolkit dll to the Toolbar in VS (2010), but all the controls are greyed out...
- The GetCompletionList function (WebMethod) I have written is in the code behind the page. Could this not be called because it has to be in a Web Service perhaps?
- I've also just realised that my function in the code behind isn't **Shared**, is this required? Because the list associated with the auto complete is dynamic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the context key parameter in your webmethod? To my knowledge, your protototype signature is wrong, you should require two params: `prefixText(String), count(int)` (at least since you've not provided a contextkey itself as an attribute). [maybe I'm missing something however]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your GetCompletionList function in a web-service (asmx is easiest).  Make sure the the web-service class has a [ScriptService] attribute and that your function has a [ScriptMethod] attribute.

You'll also need to supply the path to the web-service in your AutoCompleteExtender's "ServicePath" property (i.e. ServicePath="~/MyService.asmx")

Also, you don't need the "contextKey" parameter in your function unless you are passing a context key from your AutoCompleteExtender control.

hth

Comment: Does this mean the way I'm attempting it is not possible whatsoever? Because I would very much like to avoid using this method if possible.

Comment: You can use AutoCompleteExtender either with a web-service or using page methods.  In order to use a page method, you must first enable page methods in the scriptmanager.  The page method itself must be static (or Shared in vb).  Here is a link that walks you through using page methods instead of web-service: http://allwrong.wordpress.com/2007/03/13/ms-ajax-autocomplete-extender-using-a-page-method/

Comment: 1 issue, the way I get my auto completion search list isn't static, it calls a dynamic function that uses properties of the class. Is there a way around this? Or does the auto completion list have to be static?

Comment: The function has to be static -- there's no way to call a dynamic function on a page (the page has already expired.)  You can use the ContextKey property of the AutoCompleteExtender -- set dynamically in the page's code-behind -- to pass page-specific info into your static function, though.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Add these attributes and try it. I have implemented and it works with page behind web methods.

```
ServiceMethod="yourGetfunction"
MinimumPrefixLength="2" 
CompletionInterval="100"
EnableCaching="FALSE"
CompletionSetCount="20"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this solution: http://suggester.codeplex.com/

Demo to test: http://show-demos.net/suggester/

Its not from ALAX Toolkit but it uses ASP.NET AJAX and jQuery and has more rich functionality

Answer (score 0):

I kind of made this working:

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function GetCompletionList(ByVal prefixText As String, ByVal count As Integer) As List(Of String)
        Dim listData As New List(Of String)
        listData.Add("A")
        listData.Add("B")
        listData.Add("C")
        Return listData
    End Function
```

My html:

```
<form id="maincontent" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods = "true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
           <table style="margin-top:40px;color:White">  
            <tr>  
                <td>  
                    Type in your search:  
                </td>  
                <td>  
                    <asp:TextBox ID="searchBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
                    <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" MinimumPrefixLength="1"  
                        CompletionInterval="10" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="1" TargetControlID="searchBox"  
                        ID="AutoCompleteExtenderPersonSearch" runat="server" FirstRowSelected="false">  
                    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>  
                </td>
            </tr>  
        </table>  

    </div>
    </form>
```